# Solution for IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code

```
def countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges):
    ap=[]
    oran=[]
    for i in range(len(apples)) :
        ap[i]=apples[i]+a
    for i in range(len(oranges)) :
        oran[i]=oranges[i]+b
        
    p=0
    og=0
    for i in range(len(apples)-1) :
        if (ap[i]>s and ap[i]<s):
            p+=1
    for i in range(len(oranges)-1):
        if (oran[i]>s and oran[i]<t):
            og+=1
    print (p)
    print (og)
```

The error I am facing is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "Solution.py", line 52, in <module>
    countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges)
  File "Solution.py", line 14, in countApplesAndOranges
    ap[i]=apples[i]+a
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The original question is this ["https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/apple-and-orange/problem"](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/apple-and-orange/problem)

Thanks for any possible help out there

Answer (score 0):

ap is `[]`.
you can't just assign `ap[3]=val` because there is no `ap[3]`
what you need to do is

```
for i in range(len(apples)):
     ap.append(apples[i]+a)
```

or better:

```
for apple in apples :
        ap.append(apple+a)
```

or even better:

```
ap = [apple+a for apple in apples]
```

Comment: Compiler Message
Wrong Answer
Input (stdin)

Download
7 11
5 15
3 2
-2 2 1
5 -6
Your Output (stdout)
0
0
Expected Output

Download
1
1
'code'

This is the message I am getting

Comment: you were asking on :"list assignment index out of range". what are you asking?